# Grunt: Directory Requirements for Preprocessing

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am using Grunt's `['processhtml', 'uglify', 'concat', 'htmlmin', 'cssmin']` plugins to automate my web development. Works great. My question is regarding required directories. I currently have

```
source/
    /includes
        header.html
        footer.html
    index.html
    about.html

staging/
    (this gets auto populated by grunt with built prettified source files

public/
    (this gets auto populated by grunt with uglified production ready code
```

Do I need a staging folder? Is this normal/standard usage? Or, can I / should I place prettified built out files straight in the public folder and then have the uglify task source AND destination be the public folder? Hope my question makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use git for your project? Do you have automated deploys?

Comment: no, not using git or any continuous delivery (CD) pipeline. Right now it's just me...

Comment: Good and you use the staging folder for other than storing temporary “pretty” files?